# Sending emails with messages dependent on if statements Django

Tags: django, email

I need to send emails to different to users with different messages depending on the state of if statements in my code. Currently, I am sending emails like this:

```
send_mail(
    'Subject',
    'Body',
    'From',
    '['To']'
)
```

However, I need a way where I can change the body of the email depending on the way a user navigates the `if` statements like so:

```
# drop down to select a, b, or c
if dropdown == 'a':
    sendmail( to b,c)
if dropdown == 'b':
    sendmail(to a,c)
if dropdown == 'c':
    sendmail(to a,b)
```

I could make emails in each `if` statment, but I feel like there is a way that I could have an email template that I could populate depending where the email is being sent from.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list

```
recipients = ['a','b','c']
recipients.remove('drop down')
sendmail(recipients)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! How would I add the email bodies to those, since the email bodies will all be different in each if statement? Or is that just too out of scope?

Comment: You can use some similar mechanism for bodies also but since this answers your original question please mark as correct and post a new question but be sure to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ahhh, well with your input I'm sure I can figure out my issue, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use variables, and change their values depending on the condition.

```
subject = ''
body = ''
from = 'domain@domain.com'
recipients = ['a','b','c']

if dropdown == 'a':
    subject = 'Subject A'
    body = 'Body A'
    recipients = ['a','b','c']
elif dropdown == 'b':
    subject = 'Subject B'
    body = 'Body B'
    recipients = ['b']
elif dropdown == 'c':
    subject = 'Subject C'
    body = 'Body C'
    recipients = ['a','b']

sendmail( subject, body, from)
```

Comment: Do you have to specify the recipients in the final `sendmail`?

Comment: That;s a lot of code and it will grow if the number of recipients grows.

Comment: And you are sending to two incorrect recipients, this this approach bugs like that are the norm rather than the exception

Answer (score 0):

You could always send one mail at a time

```
sender = 'domain@domain.com'
recipients = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for recipient in recipients:
    if recipient == dropdown:
        continue
    subject = 'Subject {}'.format(recipient.upper())
    body = 'Email body for {}'.format(recipient.upper())
    sendmail(subject, body, sender, [recipient])
```

I'm guessing you have proper object and a,b,c are actually User objects.  You could use some templates, and render to string for each one. It's much better than string manipulation in the view. Suppose you have the follow

email_subject.txt

```
{{ recipient_name }}, this is the subject
```

email_body.txt (and html if you'll be doing html emails)

```
Hey {{ recipient_name }},
This is the email specially for you

From Support
```

You view could be

```
sender = 'domain@domain.com'
recipients = get_recipients_but_exclude(dropdown)
for recipient in recipients:
    subject = render_to_string('email_subject.txt', {'recipient_name': recipient.get_full_name()})
    body = render_to_string('email_body.txt', {'recipient_name': recipient.get_full_name()})
    sendmail(subject, body, sender, [recipient])
```